# WinError 193 %1 is not a valid win32 application. Django 2.05 python 3.6.2

Tags: python, postgis, geodjango, django

I will post the error below.  I did the main django tuturoials on the website without a problem.  But something happens when I change my ENGINE in settings.py to the postgis version.

This is the tutorial:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#setting-up

It might be the way I have everything installed.  It took me awhile to set up my PATH so that I could even use the ogrinfo tool.

This is what my DATABASES looks like in the settings.py:

```
'default': {
   'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
    'NAME': 'djangogeo',
    'USER': 'postgres',
    'PASSWORD': '--------',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '5432',}
```

Yes the database has been built and the postgis extensions have been applied.

The error message I am about to post shows up whether I use
    python manage.py runserver
or python manage.py make migrations.

I am not sure what to really do at this point.

```
(tutorialgis) C:\Users\Peter\lifeingis\agricom>python manage.py runserver
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors. 
<locals>.wrapper at 0x03302228>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 112, in 
inner_run
autoreload.raise_last_exception()
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
raise _exception[1]
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", 
line 24, in setup
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
app_config.import_models()
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, 
in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 978, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 114, in __new__
new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, 
connection.ops.max_name_length())
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", 
line 202, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", 
line 110, in load_backend
return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, 
in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\base.py", line 6, in 
<module>
from .features import DatabaseFeatures
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\postgis\features.py", line 1, in 
<module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.backends.base.features import BaseSpatialFeatures
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\db\backends\base\features.py", line 3, in 
<module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.models import aggregates
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\functions.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, 
GeometryField
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\db\models\fields.py", line 3, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .fields import (  # NOQA
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\forms\fields.py", line 2, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .collections import (  # NOQA
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\collections.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.geos.geometry import GEOSGeometry, 
LinearGeometryMixin
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis import gdal
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\datasource.py", line 39, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\driver.py", line 5, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\prototypes\ds.py", line 9, in <module>
from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
File "C:\Users\Peter\Envs\tutorialgis\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\gis\gdal\libgdal.py", line 47, in <module>
lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
File "c:\users\peter\appdata\local\programs\python\python36- 
32\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Could it be some of my environment settings? I used this to fix my path problems earlier 
https://gisforthought.com/setting-up-your-gdal-and-ogr-environmental-variables/

After failing multiple times I decided to try this tutorial and started from the beginning and now it is happening again.  I can't get past the 16:00 minute mark.  Please help?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jQlvPAiSCjk

Comment: I've seen this "%1 is not a valid Win32 application" error before while accidentally mixing 32-bit and 64-bit components. Check your OS and each components you installed to ensure it's all 64-bit or 32-bit.

Comment: The python is 32 bit I believe.  I know for sure the OSGeo package is 64.... Is there a 64bit python I should be using? thanks

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to add details. Comments are generally reserved for *requesting* clarification, not giving it. Please take the [Tour] , which explains how GIS SE works.